# pyspark dataframe grouping

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I'm using pyspark and i have a df like this below:

| id | time | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | A |
| 1 | 14 | A |
| 1 | 22 | B |
| 2 | 16 | B |
| 2 | 23 | B |
| 2 | 100 | C |
| 3 | 13 | C |
| 3 | 10 | C |

i want to build a new column "result" like this:

```
| id| result|
|:---- |:------|
| 1| [A -> 18 , B ->22]|
| 2| [B -> 39 , C -> 100] |
| 3| [C -> 23]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

out = df.groupBy("id","group").agg(F.sum("time").alias("time"))\
.groupBy("id").agg(F.map_from_arrays(*[F.collect_list("group"),
                                       F.collect_list("time")])
                   .alias("result"))
```

---

```
out.show()

+---+-------------------+
| id|             result|
+---+-------------------+
|  1| {B -> 22, A -> 18}|
|  3|          {C -> 23}|
|  2|{B -> 39, C -> 100}|
+---+-------------------+
```